# Android: Dropbox api, downloaded photos are rotated?

Tags: android, dropbox-api

I'm using the Dropbox Core API to download and display photos. Downloading them and writing to a FileOutputStream is easy enough with:

```
DropboxAPI.getFile(filePath, null, fos, null);
```

But the downloaded image is always rotated. If I view the image in my web browser, it displays as upright. But the image written to the FileOutputStream is rotated. Any suggestions as to why this occurs? I can't find anything provided by the metadata that describes how an image should be orientated, but possibly I'm missing something there?

It seems like it would be a mistake to simply check if the image's width is greater than it's height, and to rotate it to portrait orientation based on that?

Comment: The Dropbox API `getFile` method (which uses the /files (GET) endpoint on the Core API: https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/docs#files-GET ) just returns the raw data for the specified file. I believe rotation for images can be done either directly via the image data, or in metadata. In the case of metadata, depending on what you use to view the image, you may or may not see the expected rotation. I don't know off hand what metadata property is used for this though.

Comment: I don't see anything related to rotation/orientation in the DropboxFileInfo object returned by the getFile() method or in the Entry object, from which I get the image's path. And if instantiate an ExifInterface from the location that I saved the image, the rotation value is 0, for undefined. Any other thoughts are where I can look for the rotation value?

Comment: Do you mean `DbxFileInfo` ( https://www.dropbox.com/developers/sync/docs/android#com.dropbox.sync.android.DbxFileInfo )? That only gives Dropbox-specific metadata about the file, and not any media information from looking at the contents. I don't know much about how EXIF stores rotation information though, or how other applications display images unfortunately.